# Table horizontal lines are incomplete

Tags: tables, formatting

I am a bit lost in the result that this table is generating, seeming that the horizontal lines seem to render incompletely. Any ideas what could be causing this? Thank you.

[image]

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.6cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.8cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.3cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.6cm}|c|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{INPUTS}} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{OUTPUTS}}\\ \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & V1 & I1 & V2 & I2 & V3 & I3 & V4 & I4 \\ \hline
PS 1 & 200V AC, 400 Hz & 115V AC, 400 Hz & - & +5V & 1A & +15V & 1.5A & -15V & 1.5A & - & - \\ \hline
PS 2 & - & 115V AC,    50-400 Hz (3 Phase) & 200-300V DC & - & - & - & - & - & - & +96V & 0.2A \\ \hline
PS 3 & 220V AC, 50-400 Hz (1 Phase) & 115V AC,    50-400 Hz (1,2 \& 3 Phase) & 200-300V DC & +5V & 50A & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
PS 4 & - & - & 28V DC $\pm$ 12V & - & - & +15V & 3.5A & -15V & 3.5A & 26V AC, 400Hz & 3A \\ \hline
PS 5 & 220V AC, 50-400 Hz (1 Phase) & 115V AC,    50-400 Hz (1,2 \& 3 Phase) & 200-300V DC & - & - & +15V & 3.5A & -15V & 3.5A & - & - \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}}
```

Comment: Clearly your table is too wide and overflows into the margin. You can try using a smaller fontsize for this table and reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` to, say, 3pt of the paper?(default is 6pt). What is your document class and the format of the paper?

Comment: Thanks @Bernard ! It seems it did the trick half-way. Nevertheless, now the horizontal lines seem to still go until the end of the column (as you mentioned before, previously they also ended at that same lenght)

https://imgur.com/a/Fgo3lSZ

Comment: Anyway, \scriptsize is really very small. Perhaps you should consider swapping rows and columns: you could then use a larger font size, making the table more readable, and with a more sensible width. I don't  think tabularx is necessary here 'anyway, you have no X column, and you can have multiline standard cells if you load `makecell`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

- you not provide any information about page layout in your document, so we can only guessing
- In above image of table is assumed, that page layout is defined by default values of `geometry` package
- Using `tabularx` table environment require that at least one column had to be `X` or types derived from it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|M{7mm}|
                              M{13mm}|
                              M{25mm}|
                              M{13mm}|
                              C|C|C|C|C|C|M{12mm}|C|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{INPUTS}} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{OUTPUTS}}\\ \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & V1 & I1 & V2 & I2 & V3 & I3 & V4 & I4 \\ \hline
PS 1 & 200V AC, 400 Hz & 115V AC, 400 Hz & - & +5V & 1A & +15V & 1.5A & $-15$V & 1.5A & - & - \\ \hline
PS 2 & - & 115V AC,    50-400 Hz (3 Phase) & 200-300V DC & - & - & - & - & - & - & +96V & 0.2A \\ \hline
PS 3 & 220V AC, 50-400 Hz (1 Phase) & 115V AC,    50-400 Hz (1,2 \& 3 Phase) & 200-300V DC & +5V & 50A & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
PS 4 & - & - & 28V DC $\pm$ 12V & - & - & +15V & 3.5A & $-15$V & 3.5A & 26V AC, 400Hz & 3A \\ \hline
PS 5 & 220V AC, 50-400 Hz (1 Phase) & 115V AC,    50-400 Hz (1,2 \& 3 Phase) & 200-300V DC & - & - & +15V & 3.5A & $-15$V & 3.5A & - & - \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```